# Matrix square root and commutation

Tags: matrix

Does a square of a matrix commute with the matrix itself? I have the following code showing that it does not. Is everything fine here?

```
    MAT = {{1, 2}, {3, 4}};
FullSimplify[Sqrt[MAT].MAT.Sqrt[MAT] - MAT^2] // MatrixForm
```

Comment: Nope. Matrix sqare roots are not uniquely defined. Moreover, `Sqrt[MAT]` in _Mathematica_ is the square root applied to each component of the matrix. It is **not** a matrix square root. Try, for example, `MatrixExp[1/2 MatrixLog[MAT]]` instead. Moreover, the square of a matrix is `MAT.MAT` or `MatrixPower[Mat,2]`, not `MAT^2`.

Comment: When a matrix has a square root, yes, it commutes with the matrix in the sense of matrix products.

Answer (score 5):

`Sqrt[MAT]` is not the matrix square root of MAT, but the matrix of the square roots of the elements of MAT. Compare with `MatrixPower[MAT, 1/2]`.

Answer (score 3):

Are you asking about the square of a matrix, or the square root of a matrix.  Let's assume you are asking about a square root of a matrix (may not be unique).  If we define a square root of matrix M to be Q, such that QQ=M, then yes, Q and M commute.  Proof:  QM = Q(QQ) = (QQ)Q = MQ.

Here is an example coded in Mathematica:

```
 A = {{9, 0}, {0, 4}}; B = {{1, 0}, {0, 1}}; 
 M = A + RandomVariate[MatrixNormalDistribution[B, B]];
 Q = MatrixPower[M, 1/2];
 Print["M = ", M // MatrixForm];
 Print["Q = ", Q // MatrixForm];
 Print["MQ = ", M.Q  // MatrixForm];
 Print["QM = ", Q.M  // MatrixForm];
```

We can verify (by inspection) that Q is a square root of M:

```
 Print["M = ", M // MatrixForm];
 Print["QQ = ", Q.Q // MatrixForm];
```